# Can we define the Mandelbrot set in terms of the generating function of the Catalan numbers?

Tags: co.combinatorics, limits-and-convergence, generating-functions, fractals, catalan-numbers

For each complex number $c$, define $P_{0}(c)=0$ and $P_{n+1}(c) = (P_{n}(c))^{2} + c$ .  The Mandelbrot set is the set of complex numbers c for which $|P_{n}(c)|$ stays bounded as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

$P_{n}(c)$ is a polynomial in $c$.   [Donald D. Cross noticed in 2005](http://cosinekitty.com/mandel_poly.html) that the leading terms settle down
$p_{0} + p_{1}c + p_{2} c^{2} + p_{3} c^{3} + ... = c + c^{2} + 2c^{3} + 5c^{4} + ...$  and submitted them to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences ([A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108)).  It was subsequently noticed that these are the terms for the generating function $P(c)$ of the Catalan numbers, which is defined by: $P(c) = cP(c)^{2} + 1$.  Indeed, $p_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p_{i}p_{n-i}$.

Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick mention this connection with enthusiasm in their definitive textbook [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf), 2009, available online for free. See pages 535-537 and also the link to the theta function is discussed on page 328-330.  Curiously, there is no mention of the Mandelbrot set in Richard Stanley's 2015 book [Catalan Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107427746).

My question is whether $P(c)$ can be used to define the Mandelbrot set.  Is it the case that $|P(c)|$ is bounded if and only if $|P_{n}(c)|$ stays bounded as $n\rightarrow \infty$ ?  Is the Mandelbrot set simply the set for which $P(c)$ is bounded?

Comment: What do you mean?  $P(c) = (1 - \sqrt{1-4c})/(2c)$  is an analytic function (except for a branch cut on $[1/4, \infty)$).  It doesn't do anything special on the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: Robert, that helps, thank you.  So does that mean $P(c)$ is well defined for all c except on the branch cut?

Comment: I am intrigued by this question, but I don't yet have anything intelligent to contribute, except that a search on "mandelbrot catalan" shows that someone else noticed this in 1999:  

http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=162350

Comment: @AndriusKulikauskas :  I'm puzzled as to why you're asking this here since I already answered your question when you asked it on FOM back in May.  http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2016-May/019822.html

Comment: @NathanReading thank you for that link! Yes, I think I'm asking the same question.  The answer they got is helpful for me.

Comment: @TimothyChow yes, thank you for your reply then.  I imagine these matters may be obvious to you and others, but I don't know much complex analysis, only the undergraduate course I took more than 30 years ago.  Also, I may be imprecisely using terms, for example, instead of generating function perhaps I should better say formal power series $P(c)$.  To break down my question:  A) For what c does $P(c)$ converge, diverge, and not diverge?  B) The coefficients of $P(c)$ are positive integers and greater than the ones for $P_n(c)$. What can we say about $P-P_n(c)$?